# AdMob banner doesnt showing

Tags: java, android, libgdx, admob

I have been trying to add a banner to my game on Libgdx and i have read some documentation on it and eventually wrote this code:

```
    protected void onCreate (Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    AndroidApplicationConfiguration config = new AndroidApplicationConfiguration();
    //initialize(new GameMain(), config);

    RelativeLayout layout = new RelativeLayout(this);

    requestWindowFeature(Window.FEATURE_NO_TITLE);
    getWindow().setFlags(WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_FULLSCREEN, 
            WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_FULLSCREEN);
    getWindow().clearFlags(WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_FORCE_NOT_FULLSCREEN);

    View gameView = initializeForView(new GameMain(), config);
    AdView adView = new AdView(this);
    adView.setAdSize(AdSize.BANNER);
    adView.setAdUnitId("pub-xxxxxxxxxxx");
    AdRequest adRequest = new AdRequest.Builder().build();
    adView.loadAd(adRequest);
    layout.addView(gameView);

    RelativeLayout.LayoutParams adParams = 
            new RelativeLayout.LayoutParams(RelativeLayout.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT, 
                    RelativeLayout.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT);
        adParams.addRule(RelativeLayout.CENTER_HORIZONTAL);
        adParams.addRule(RelativeLayout.CENTER_HORIZONTAL);
        layout.addView(adView, adParams);
        setContentView(layout);

        }
    }
```

The problem is that it doesn't show the ads and i cant figure out why.
(the problem is not the publisher id i have just changed it to put it here, in the code it is my real publisher id)

Can't anyone spot the problem?

Comment: Have you checked the logs? It may show whats happening with the ad.

Comment: I found this on the CatLog but i dont know what it means or what to do with it.                                                                                                                          


01-19 19:45:59.275: E/dalvikvm(32407): Could not find class 'android.support.v4.app.FragmentActivity', referenced from method com.google.android.gms.common.GooglePlayServicesUtil.showErrorDialogFragment
01-19 19:45:59.275: W/dalvikvm(32407): VFY: unable to resolve instanceof 173 (Landroid/support/v4/app/FragmentActivity;) in Lcom/google/android/gms/common/GooglePlayServicesUtil;

Answer (score 0):

You seem to be missing the Android support library from your imports.

Answer (score 0):

maybe this helps https://github.com/libgdx/libgdx/wiki/Google-Play-Game-Services-in-LibGDX

look bulild.gradle:

```
project(":android") {
apply plugin: "android"

configurations { natives }

dependencies {
    compile project(":core")
    compile project(":libraries:BaseGameUtils")
    compile "com.badlogicgames.gdx:gdx-backend-android:$gdxVersion"
    natives "com.badlogicgames.gdx:gdx-platform:$gdxVersion:natives-armeabi"
    natives "com.badlogicgames.gdx:gdx-platform:$gdxVersion:natives-armeabi-v7a"
    natives "com.badlogicgames.gdx:gdx-platform:$gdxVersion:natives-x86"
    compile "com.badlogicgames.gdx:gdx-box2d:$gdxVersion"
    natives "com.badlogicgames.gdx:gdx-box2d-platform:$gdxVersion:natives-armeabi"
    natives "com.badlogicgames.gdx:gdx-box2d-platform:$gdxVersion:natives-armeabi-v7a"
    natives "com.badlogicgames.gdx:gdx-box2d-platform:$gdxVersion:natives-x86"

    compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:20.0.+'
    compile 'com.android.support:support-v4:20.0.+'
    compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services:5.0+'
}

}
```